# 'AttributeError:' when I try to unpickle dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pickle

I have made a program on python 3.5 which you can find out the password linked to a username, make a new password for an existing user and add a new user and password to the dictionary then pickles it so every time I load the program all the usernames and passwords will be there.

The error that comes up is after you create the pickle file(after running it for the first time) then on line 6 the error

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NewPass' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

occurs.

Here is my script:

```
import sys
import pickle
import os

if os.path.exists("branston.p"):
    LOGG = pickle.load(open('branston.p', 'rb'))

else:
    LOGG = {'Sam': ('CHRIST')}

def Find():
    Username = input("Say a Username.")
    print (LOGG[Username])

def NewPass():
    Username = Input("Enter your username.")

    Newpass = input("Enter your new password")

    if NewPass == input("Confirm password"):
        LOGG[Username] = (NewPass)

def NewEntry():

    NewUser = input("Enter your new username.")
    Newpass = input("Enter your new password.")

    LOGG[NewUser] = (NewPass)

loop = True

while loop == True:

    function = input("Say what you want me to do.'Find', 'NewPass', 'NewEntry', 'Stop'.")

    if function == ("Find"):
        Find()

    elif function == ("NewPass"):
        NewPass()

    elif function == ("NewEntry"):
        NewEntry()

    elif function == ("Stop"):
        f = open('branston.p', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(LOGG, f)

        f.close()
        sys.exit()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Python is case sensitive.  `Newpass` is not the same thing as `NewPass`.

Comment: Don't name your variables same as your functions. It looks like you pickled a function.

Comment: Please have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). With proper naming conventions, this typo is trivial to spot.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this

```
LOGG[NewUser] = (NewPass)
```

You are assigning the function `NewPass` to your dict entry. You are probably intending to assign the password string and therefore it should be.

```
LOGG[NewUser] = Newpass
```

Note: Parenthesis are superfluous. I'd also suggest avoiding using upper case letters as the first character of your variable names, as otherwise it is easy to confuse variable and function names.